PowerPoint Macro Causes Restart When Triggered from Ribbon Button (Works Fine via VBA Editor)
I'm facing an issue with a PowerPoint VBA macro that resizes and adjusts images on slides. Here's the problem:
When I run the macro via a button I added to the ribbon, PowerPoint restarts about every 5-6 times I click the button.
When I run the exact same macro from the VBA editor (using F5), it works perfectly every time—no crashes.
This issue only happens on my work computer, not on my personal computer, where it works fine regardless of how I trigger it.
Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening, or suggestions on how to debug/fix it? It seems like it could be related to memory issues or how PowerPoint interacts with the ribbon interface, but I’m not sure.
To troubleshoot, I've tried the following:

Closed unnecessary programs on my work computer to ensure there are enough system resources.
Simplified the macro code as much as possible, but it's already very basic—just adjusting the image size and positioning it on the slide.

Sub AdjustImageOnSlide()
    SavePresentation 
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim sld As slide
    Dim shp As shape
    Dim foundImage As Boolean

    
    If Not ActiveWindow Is Nothing Then
        If ActiveWindow.View.Type = ppViewSlide Or ActiveWindow.View.Type = ppViewNormal Then
            Set sld = ActiveWindow.View.slide
        Else
            MsgBox "Veuillez vous assurer qu'une diapositive est active avant d'exécuter cette macro.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ElseIf SlideShowWindows.Count > 0 Then
        Set sld = SlideShowWindows(1).View.slide
    Else
        MsgBox "Aucune diapositive active trouvée.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    foundImage = False

    
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        
        If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
            If shp.Tags.Count = 0 Or shp.Tags("Adjusted") <> "Yes" Then
                
                shp.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                shp.Width = 30.44 * 28.35     ' Largeur 
                shp.Height = 16.19 * 28.35    ' Hauteur 
                shp.Left = 2.5 * 28.35        ' 2,5 cm
                shp.Top = 1 * 28.35           ' 1 cm 
                shp.ZOrder msoSendToBack

                
                shp.Tags.Add "Adjusted", "Yes"

                foundImage = True
                DoEvents 
            End If
        End If
    Next shp

    If Not foundImage Then
        MsgBox "Aucune nouvelle image à ajuster sur la diapositive.", vbInformation, "Information"
    End If

    
    Set sld = Nothing
    Set shp = Nothing

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Une erreur s'est produite : " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Erreur dans AdjustImageOnSlide"
    Resume Next
End Sub


I tested it out it is working fine. i have to remove "SavePresentation" line as that module is not provided. The issue is probably in your xml code. happened to me once can't remember why it was happening.

Hi @abdullah,
You are rigth SavePresentation doesn't work because it's another fonction, that i didn't put here. However as i told in main message i face restart PP problem only on work computer, same code on my PC work with no issues.
